# Are events executed in another thread?

Tags: wpf, events, c#-4.0

Are event handlers always executed in parallel, in a thread *other than* the main thread?

Thanks.

Comment: Events are executed in a thread which fires the event. Not sure what your question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event Handlers are executed in the same thread as the thread in which the event was raised.  If you 'trigger' the event in a background thread, then the event handlers will be run on that same background thread.  If you raise the event on the "main" thread, they will be executed on the main thread.

Event handlers are executed one at a time (synchronously).

Event handlers are sometimes called "[multicast delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175.aspx)," and that name is apt; event handlers are nothing more than a list of functions to call, whenever an 'event' is triggered.  We cannot call the "next" function in the list, until the previous one has completed.

Raising an event is akin to something like this:

```
List<Action> eventHandlers = new List<Action>();
foreach(Action currentHandler in eventHandlers)
{
    currentHandler();
}
```

Comment: You may even get that list by [`Delegate.GetInvocationList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx).